# Ratio of area slices under an exponential function

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I am trying to prove this:
[image]

I started by defining $A$ and $B$. Since $A$ is the area under $f(x)$ from $n$ to $n-1$:

$$A = \int^n_{n-1} a^x \, dx \\= \frac{a^n}{\ln(a)} - \frac{a^{n-1}}{\ln(a)}$$

and since $B$ is the area from $n-1$ to $n-2$:

$$B = \int^{n-1}_{n-2} a^x \, dx \\= \frac{a^{n-1}}{\ln(a)} - \frac{a^{n-2}}{\ln(a)}$$

so:

\begin{align}
\frac{A}{B} & = \frac{\frac{a^n}{\ln(a)} - \frac{a^{n-1}}{\ln(a)}}{\frac{a^{n-1}}{\ln(a)} - \frac{a^{n-2}}{\ln(a)}}\\[10pt]
& = \left(\frac{a^n - a^{n-1}}{\ln(a)}\right)\left(\frac{\ln(a)}{a^{n-1} - a^{n-2}}\right)\\[10pt]
&=\frac{a^n - a^{n-1}}{a^{n-1} - a^{n-2}}\\[10pt]
&=\frac{a(a^{n-1} - a^{n-2})}{(a^{n-1} - a^{n-2})}\\[10pt]
& = a
\end{align}

so:
$$\frac{A}{B} = a$$
Is this proof correct?

Comment: It seems to be correct.

Comment: Yes. It's neat. If a criticism is badly needed, then I would just point out that you need to mention: $a > 0$ and $a \neq 1$, and $n > 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct but it's overkill in that it can be done without finding the antiderivative:

\begin{align}
A = \int_{n-1}^n a^x\,dx = a\int_{n-1}^n a^{x-1}\,dx = a\int_{n-2}^{n-1} a^w\,dw = aB.
\end{align}

Here we have $w=x-1$, so that $dw=dx$ and as $x$ goes from $n-1$ to $n$, then $w$ goes from $n-2$ to $n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof is correct.

Also note the following:
$$f(n)-f(n-1)=a^{n-1}(a-1)$$
$$f(n-1)-f(n-2)=a^{n-2}(a-1)$$
$$\therefore\dfrac{f(n)-f(n-1)}{f(n-1)-f(n-2)}=a$$